# Read file, not same result on windows or linux

Tags: python, linux, windows

I have the same code, I run it on a **raspberry** and on **win7**, and I can't have the same result

The code:

```
with open('file','rb') as fd:
    ttt = fd.read(4)
    print (ttt)
    seed = unpack('>I', fd.read(4))[0]
    print str(seed)
```

On **linux** I have the good result.

```
b')M7\xeb'
692926443
```

But on **windows**, I have

```
>M7ù
1401564715
```

Why this difference ? Why on **linux** I have more than 4 char ?

Edit:
I have finaly find a way to have same result.

```
import codecs
with codecs.open("G:/InsideReCaptcha-master/enc", mode='rb') as fd:
    ttt = fd.read(4)
    seed = unpack('>I', ttt)[0]
```

Not sure all the code is usefull, but it works.

Comment: On Linux you're using Python 3. The integer 692926443 is the unpacked value of `b')M7\xeb'`, so in the Linux test, bytes 4-7 of "file" are identical to bytes 0-3. On Windows you're using Python 2 (because `print(ttt)` prints a regular string instead of a `bytes` literal). Also, the file on Windows instead has `b'>M7ù'` in bytes 0-3. I can't say what the byte value of `'ù'` is because it depends on the console codepage. The file on Windows also has `b'S\x8a.+'` in bytes 4-7, which unpacks to 1401564715.

Comment: Remove your solution from the *question* and post it as an *answer*.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux output is the binary string representation, which is why it is shown as b'[STRING]'. The accented character is shown as an escaped ASCII alternative. The Windows output is the actual string representation. To make them the same, use decode:

print b'a string'.decode('ascii')

Comment: print b'a string'.decode('ascii') on windows ? to have same result than on linux ?

Comment: Python for Windows seems to be automatically decoding the string. Linux is not and is letting you know it is a binary string. If you want consistent results, especially when using non-ASCII or utf-8 character sets, do the decoding yourself using the appropriate character set.